# Real time log analysis Scala or Java solutions

Tags: java, scala, logging, real-time, analysis

I'm looking for real time log analysis library or framework in Java/Scala.

Some suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps storm could fit your requirements (which you describe very vague :-))
http://storm-project.net/

Comment: More specifically you could look at [storm-scribe](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib/tree/master/storm-scribe)